# jQuery show not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

We have a span that we try to show in IE8(contract thing) with `jQuery('#processingDiv').show();`

We are using jquery-1.3.2.min.js

We declare the span like this:

```
jQuery("#processingDiv").bind("ajaxSend", function(){
    jQuery(this).show();
 }).bind("ajaxComplete", function(){
     jQuery(this).hide();
 });
```

This is the HTML for the processingDiv span

```
<span id="processingDiv" style="width: 430px;"
        class="boldblue"> Processing... <img src="<icis2:icisRes/>images/loadingBar.gif" border="0"
        alt="Processing..." />
</span>
```

We don't see the span except when the javascript confirm runs.

```
if(confirm("Warning! You are processing this filing without appending signature pages to any documents. Continue?")){
    checkDraftTemplateAndSubmitForm(form);
} else {
    jQuery('#processingDiv').hide();
    return false;
}
```

I tried this after some research with no luck:

```
jQuery('#processingDiv').css({"visibility":"visible"});
```

I also tried changing the name to see if there was any naming conflicts.

This is seems bizare, does anyone have any ideas about this?

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: It's not as simple as upgrading, but you should really upgrade your version of jQuery; 1.3.2 is quite old. I didn't fully read your code, but I wouldn't be surprised if upgrading fixed whatever problem you have

Comment: jQuery 1.3.2 AND IE8? I'm so sorry! - But, does running `jQuery("#processingDiv").show()` normally work?

Comment: Have you tried using .toggle()?

Comment: The global ajax events are usually attached to the document, are you sure those event handlers even fire ?

Comment: FYI, `show` and `hide` update the `display` style, not `visibility`. `hide` is `display: none`, `show` is `display: inline` (or `inline-block`, depending on the type of element).

Comment: Also, are you sure it just isn't happening so fast that you can't see it? I highly doubt that since we're talking about IE8, but... maybe? What exactly do you mean by you see it when you use the confirm?

Comment: Is this an `async: false` request?

Comment: Testing, it seems to work -> http://jsfiddle.net/4pqKr/

Comment: If the span is visible when the confirm is showing, but then dissapears, it's probably because the ajax call has completed.

Comment: @Ian tried to update to jquery-1.6.2.min.js with no change.

Comment: @PlaceUserNameHere I tried toggle() with the same result. Thanks

Comment: @KevinB No it is not, do you think it should be?

Comment: No it shouldn't be synchronous.